Particle number expectation value in QuTip
I am learning now to use QuTiP by going through their documentation site. I am trying to understand what does the argument - particle number expectation value in thermal density matrix do? How does it affect the density matrix? I tried for different values of n ranging from 0 to 10 and 100 for a 4X4 matrix. For n = 0, I get a density matrix with only the first entry being non-zero (takes the value of 1). For 100, it's a diagonal matrix - each diagonal element has a value of 0.25. For the remaining values, I noticed that it gives the max eigenvalue for the first entry (I am guessing its due to the singular value decomposition in which you arrange the eigenvalues in decreasing order).
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
